# Is "drownded" a word?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, is-it-a-word, conjugation

Is there such a word as "*drownded*"? I would say "*drowned*" but I am hearing "*drownded*" so often I am beginning to wonder.

For example:

> He went into the deepest waters and drownded.

Comment: Drownded can be observed in Lord of the Rings, Book 1, Chapter 1 "A Long-Expected Party"

Comment: It also shows up in  the Marriott Edgar monologue [Albert and the Lion](http://www.ex-lancs.com/lancashire_dialect_poetry.htm)  **Nah, thi dint think much tu thocean  , waves wur all figgly an small, thur wur no wrecks an nobody drownded,  fact,  nowt much to laugh  at adall**    from about the same period, but that's dialect as are the Tolkien references.

Comment: We also occasionally see *drownt* and *drount*. *Drount* appears to be Scottish. *Drownt* may be a local thing, but "looking like a drownt rat" is the way that idiom is said. https://books.google.com/books?id=-1GvtnqQT_8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=drownt+boy&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNnfmw0_DRAhWISCYKHZRsAmkQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=drownt%20boy&f=false

Comment: I've certainly heard young kids use the term.  It makes perfect sense to a 6-year-old.

Comment: I came across this when correcting my 14 year old son tonight. He said 'drownded'. While we are black, My mother taught me that to say such is incorrect...black english...aka ebonics. It's interesting to find out that the use of this seemingly incorrect word is found in other cultures. I swear I thought it was just our country black folks lol

Comment: @LisaHawkins It has nothing necessarily with black english at all. Kids are smart and so are uneducated speakers (not referring here to black speakers). They know that ED is a past tense morpheme, so they add it all over the place. Then, you get the *so-called educated speakers* (like some TV presenters) saying: I had went and I had spoken instead of gone and spoken. Drives me nuts. And I can perfectly well see a white kid saying drownded before being corrected by a parent or teacher.

Answer (score 25):

*Drownd* is an archaic form of *drown* from which *drownded* is an archaic form of *drowned*. It is still found in some dialects either by survival or by emphasis of the *-ed* since the rhymes-with-round sound of *drowned* may not sound as obviously past-tense to some ears as others.

It's incorrectly frowned upon as incorrect, by people whose dialects did not retain *drownd* and *drownded*, and worth avoiding for that reason, especially in writing - so as to not only be correct, but to be seen to be correct.

But likewise, since it isn't really incorrect, the only time it is appropriate to criticise someone for using it is if you are enforcing a style-guide (when you can criticise any decision that goes against it). Those using it are not wrong.

Edit: In the dialect I grew up with, we were familiar with all four of *drownd*, *drownded*, *drown* and *drowned*. We knew that the latter two were received English, and would use them in writing, or when we wished to avoid dialectical words to "speak proper". I did not know they were retentions (my dialect has a good few retentions, some Hibernicisms, some borrowings from Ulster-Scots, and some presumably inventions of its own, but only as someone with an interest in such matters in later life do I know a bit about which are which), but we did use them. In general speech we favoured *drown* and *drownded* because *drownd* and *drowned* sound quite close to each other, while *drown* and *drownded* are clearly differentiated>

Comment: I think it might be construed as wrong because it sounds like the person is saying "drowned-ed", like a little kid might.

Comment: @JoeZeng that's what I mean when I say that while in some dialects it exists from survival, it may be that in others it came from emphasis upon the *ed*. Consider that if we wanted to stress that something was in the past tense we might well put extra stress on the *-ed* part of the word that doesn't exist in the normal pronunciation. Whether kids do it or not doesn't affect whether it is now a full part of a given dialect.

Comment: I think your use if 'correct' is too academic. Most native speakers of -all- current varieties of English would regard 'drownded' as terribly incorrect.

Comment: @Mitch I think your "all" is factually correct there. I hope it is, and you aren't saying that some of us are in some way inferior to those who grew up in other parts of the English-speaking world.

Comment: @Mitch, though you do make me think that adding a bit about the current variety of English I grew up with, might be worthwhile.

Comment: Tolkien: "Save me, Mr. Frodo!" gasped Sam. "I'm drownded. I can't see your hand."

Comment: What @Mitch said. Jon, I think you're elevating the status of "regional dialect" well beyond what is justifiable in the context of today's electronically connected world. Even if *most* older speakers in your area use *drownded* rather than *drowned* (which I frankly doubt), most younger speakers will hear/read the standard form far more often. And given that the non-standard form could easily be perceived as childish/uneducated, they have a serious vested interest in not wanting to perpetuate it. Effectively, it is therefore "incorrect", whatever the etymological/regional antecedents.

Comment: @FumbleFingers are we only to restrict "correct" to what is standard English, and speak of dialect only as a deviation into error regardless of context? I stand by my answer; it is dialectical English, found in several dialects, and is appropriate in cases where dialectical English is appropriate.

Comment: @Jon: I don't want to be drawn into making an unjustifiable generalisation - there's dialect and there's dialect. In my (Sussex) youth, we used *flittermouse, prickleback* for *bat, hedgehog*, for example, but I only use those facetiously/nostalgically today. On the other hand, I've no compunction about using *chipper* (cheerful) in informal conversation even if I suspect I'm talking to someone who may not be familiar with it. It doesn't sound childish to me, and context usually makes it obvious what I mean, so I like to use it for a bit of added "colour".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would use neither *chipper* nor *drownded* in formal writing (unless as quoted dialect). I most certainly would have used *drownded* then in a context where I would now use *chipper*, having moved in the meantime from somewhere that had *drownded* and *chip shops* to somewhere with *drowned* and *chippers* (and less concern about drowning, not being a fishing village) and having gone native a bit. *Drownded* was certainly living dialect as we spoke it, not part of a history lesson.

Comment: @Jon: I think you miss my point. I was referring to language change *in my area, in my lifetime*, not "history lessons". Things have probably moved faster where I live (Crawley, pop. over 100K now, but barely 10K even including all the surrounding villages when I was born a few miles away). Being a "New Town", we had a massive Cockney influx from London, and we've now got a burgeoning immigrant component, *plus* the "stockbroker belt" effect. Dialects don't last long in such circumstances!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm still in touch with people from the area, and it's at least as current as when the Greenhill sank in 2006. I also asked my partner "'Drownded'—country or long time ago?" and she reckoned country, which is about as much as I can do as a survey currently!

Comment: Here is another quote from "The Lord of the Rings"
_A decent respectable hobbit was Mr. Drogo Baggins; there was never much to tell of him, till he was **drownded**._

Comment: The fact that I have only ever heard this from small children, who invent it as it "sounds" more past tense than "drowned" by making the "ed" clearer, makes me see it as wrong. It may be dialectical in some places, but that isn't the case for the vast majority of the English world, where it is just a mistake.

Comment: Where is the proof re drownded. Personally, I think people speak like they speak but in the grammar game, it ain't kosher. Try getting into Yale or Harvard with that. :) Language is a game and the playing board is not even.

Answer (score 14):

The OED (Oxford English Dictionary) gives *drownded* as an alternative to *drowned* and there are ten citations throughout the dictionary illustrating its earlier use, but its use now is described as ‘vulgar’.

Stick to *drowned*.

Comment: Not [online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=drownd) - is the free online version a limited subset of the full dictionary?

Comment: @Stuart. This is the OED: http://www.oed.com/. It requires a paid subscription. The various other Oxford dictionaries are not the same thing.

Comment: @Barrie: I think it was you who altered me to the fact that (in the UK, at least), you can access OED with your library card number.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Other works of reference too.

Answer (score 7):

*Merriam-Webster's 3rd Unabridged Dictionary of English* (MW3UDE) lists "drownded" as a **nonstandard** spelling of *drowned*, which means that it has enough history to justify its use, but that it's probably not going to be seen very often, if ever, in formal English writing. *Drowned* is the current standard spelling.

Answer (score 3):

I have known people who say "drowned" as the present tense (i.e. "Without a life-guard, people will drowned"), drownded as the past tense, as well as "drownding" instead of drowning. I think it is common in the Midwest.

Comment: This is a useful answer because it also confirms Jon Hanna's assertion that "drownded" is *it is dialectical English, found in several dialects*

Answer (score 0):

4 year old grandson says "killded" instead of "killed", so I looked up drownded on Google. I was not surprised to see that it is in some dialects of English.

I also found "killded" on Google.

Comment: BTW...not my downvote...personally I think it is bad form to DV new users.

Answer (score -1):

c1850 – c1950 the heyday of *drownded*:

[image]

Too early to call it entirely wrong or deprecate it, perhaps.

Comment: Heyday? What about 'drowned'? You're only comparing 'drownded' with 'drownd', [two rare alternatives to 'drowned'](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drownd%2C+drownded%2C+drowned&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). I dont think it is -that- early to judge.

Comment: @Mitch Including *drowned* will definitely drown both these lines in the graph because of the huge difference. You have seen it happen, right? We can only compare comparables.

Comment: It was Willie what got drownded in the deep blue sea.

Comment: This question wasn't asking to compare two archaic forms, but to ask if "drownded" is a correct or standard verbal past tense of "drown." This graph doesn't really help answer that.

Answer (score -2):

I believe in my mind that drowned pertains to someone that entered deep water and never reemerged.

In relation to drownded, that is someone who has got extremely wet, from the rain, for example

Comment: David, you may have a good answer, but it needs citation from a reliable source to be accepted. You might want to look at successful answers to other questions.

Comment: "Drowned" has no connotation of depth: you can drown in a puddle. It's also common to use "drown" in a metaphorical sense (e.g. drowning in paperwork), so using the old-fashioned "drownded" in the same way would be no surprise.